# filter table rows based on table detail name and text

Tags: jquery

How can jQuery filter rows in an HTML table be using the name attribute in the td tag and an option value selected by the user from a drop down box?

Here is the HTML:

```
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h3>filtering table rows</h3>
<label>filter primary</label>
<select>
  <option></option>
  <option>Watertown</option>
  <option>Rockford</option>
  <option>Springfield</option>
  <option>Evansville</option>
</select>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>primary</th>
    <th>secondary</th>
    <th>mode</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>101</td>
    <td name="primary">Watertown</td>
    <td name="secondary">Rockford</td>
    <td>bus</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>102</td>
    <td name="primary">Springfield</td>
    <td name="secondary">Watertown</td>
    <td>car</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>103</td>
    <td name="primary">Evansville</td>
    <td name="secondary">Watertown</td>
    <td>bus</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Here is what I have so far on the jQuery:

```
// attach event to select box
$('select').on('change', filter);

// filter function
function filter() {
    var selectedOption = $('select').find(':selected').text();

$('td').hide();
$('tr').each(function() {
    $.each(this.cells, function() {
    // need a way to isolate this.cells (td tags) with name attribute equal to "primary" and text within that td tag equal to selectedOption, then hide that table row
  });
});
}
```

The jQuery doesn't work yet - I'm stuck on how to isolate the needed row(s).

For instance, if the user selects Watertown for the primary filter, the table should display just 1 row - the row that has Watertown shown in the primary column.

[image]

Comment: do you want to filter only based on `<td name="primary">?`

Comment: Yes, I want the filter based only on `<td name="primary">`.

Comment: I have an answer for you then.check below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Vpa's post, here is what I arrived at for the final code:

```
// attach event to select box
$('select').on('change', filter);

// filter function
function filter() {
    var selectedOption = $('select').find(':selected').text();

    if (selectedOption) {
    $('tr').hide();
  $('tr').each(function() {
    if($(this).find('[name=primary]').text() == selectedOption) {
    $(this).show();
    }
  });
  $('tr:first').show();
  } else {
    $('tr').show();
  }
}
```

This version shows the table header row at all times.  Also, if the user selects the blank option, all of the table rows are displayed.

Answer (score 1):

You have to display table data based on your selected value

**Update** I gave `<tr id="tableHeading">` to display the table header

**Update again** remove `<tr id>` and add `tr:first-child` in code to display table header

```js
$('select').on('change', filter);

// filter function
function filter() {
    var selectedOption = $('select').find(':selected').val();
    $('tr').each(function(){
         if($(this).find('td[name=primary]').text() == selectedOption){
            $('tr:first-child').show();
            $(this).show();
         }else{
            $('tr:first-child').show();
            $(this).hide();
         }
      });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option></option>
  <option>Watertown</option>
  <option>Rockford</option>
  <option>Springfield</option>
  <option>Evansville</option>
</select>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>primary</th>
    <th>secondary</th>
    <th>mode</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>101</td>
    <td name="primary">Watertown</td>
    <td name="secondary">Rockford</td>
    <td>bus</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>102</td>
    <td name="primary">Springfield</td>
    <td name="secondary">Watertown</td>
    <td>car</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>103</td>
    <td name="primary">Evansville</td>
    <td name="secondary">Watertown</td>
    <td>bus</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I could not get this to work.  It didn't do anything to the table - all rows still showed when an item was selected from the drop down.  (By the way, I did not give the down vote).

Comment: In my snippet? everything works for me... and even in here also it's working. Let me check again

Comment: I must've had a typo the first time.  I got it working on my machine like how the snippet is working here.  The only problem is, it hides the table header row.  What should be modified so it doesn't hide that row?

Comment: The snippet works now.  Unfortunately, in the Production code I do not have the ability to assign an id to the <tr> that holds the <th>s so I'll need to find an alternative.  Got any creative ideas?

Comment: yeah, we can easily use `tr:first-child` to show that, please take a look at my updated snippet

Comment: Nice!  I'll post my final code - it is just a condensed version of yours.

Comment: yeah, my code is a little longer than some people, anyway learning never stops..hehe

Answer (score 1):

You need to check whether the table td value matches with the selected option, and if  matches then make that  show. Here is what you can do.

```js
$('select').on('change', filter);

// filter function
function filter() {
    var selectedOption = $('select').find(':selected').text();

$('tr').hide();
$('tr:first').show();
$('table tr').each(function() {
    if($(this).find('[name=primary]').text() == selectedOption){
      $(this).show();
    }
});
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h3>filtering table rows</h3>
<label>filter primary</label>
<select>
  <option></option>
  <option>Watertown</option>
  <option>Rockford</option>
  <option>Springfield</option>
  <option>Evansville</option>
</select>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>primary</th>
    <th>secondary</th>
    <th>mode</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>101</td>
    <td name="primary">Watertown</td>
    <td name="secondary">Rockford</td>
    <td>bus</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>102</td>
    <td name="primary">Springfield</td>
    <td name="secondary">Watertown</td>
    <td>car</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>103</td>
    <td name="primary">Evansville</td>
    <td name="secondary">Watertown</td>
    <td>bus</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: This resulted in hiding all rows, including the table header row.

Comment: @knot22 i am also here . Have an answer :):)